# How to write decoder from date to date in smooks java to java

Tags: smooks

I am preparing Java object from json using ObjectMapper. Here is the json data

```
"dateTimeSent" : "LongValue"
```

Source and target both java classes have field is java.util.Date type.
I tried mapping of like this

```
 <jb:value property="dtSent" data="dateTimeSent" decoder="Date">
        <jb:decodeParam name="format">EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy</jb:decodeParam>
 </jb:value>
```

In documentation it is mentioned that this decoder used to encode/decode from String to java.util.Date. Is that i need to write custom decoder for that. If yes please let me know how to write. I am new to smooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As smooks encode/decode from String to java.util.Date/java.sql.Date/ java.util.Calendar/java.sql.Time/java.sql.Timestamp. My use case, i have to decode from date to date. So i had created one more variable in source class with setter and getter like - `private String modeifiedDateTimeSent`

I am mapping with modifiedDateTimeSent variable in smooks-config.xml

```
<jb:value property="dtSent" data="modeifiedDateTimeSent" decoder="Date">
    <jb:decodeParam name="format">yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</jb:decodeParam>
</jb:value>
```

Next, I have to set the value in the variable before mapping java class A to Class B.

```
    Date modifiedDtTimeSent = order.getLr().getAdminSection().getDateTimeSent();
    String modifiedDtTimeSentString = getDateAsString(modifiedDtTimeSent,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    object.setModifieddatetimesent(modifiedDtTimeSentString);
```

Then finally, do your smooks java to java convertion -

```
        Smooks smooks =  new Smooks("smooks-config.xml");
        ExecutionContext executionContext = smooks.createExecutionContext();
        JavaSource source = new JavaSource(object);
        JavaResult result = new JavaResult();
        smooks.filterSource(executionContext, source, result);
        ConvertedClass cc = (IimLocalResponse) result.getBean("xyz");
```

Hope this will help.